# How to make image availible at an arbitrary URL with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Having a working WordPress installation, is it possible to have an image at an arbitrary URL on the WordPress site?

E.g. http://mysite.wordpress.com/this/is/an/arbitrary/path/image.png

Answer (score 1):

you can use `wp_upload_bits()` function with some parameters.

here is an Example for that.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['your-file-input']['name']) && sizeof($_FILES['your-file-input']['name'])){
    $file = wp_upload_bits(sanitize_file_name($_FILES['your-file-input']['name']),null,file_get_contents($_FILES['your-input-file']['tmp_name']),'path/to');
    print_r($file);// it returns an array of file information [url/size/type...]
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the returned URL will always be under the Wordpress uploads basedir, e.g. http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/example.pdf.
While what I need is to set the url from the root:
E.g. http://example.com/arbitrary/path/2010/03/example.pdf

Comment: how about change the `wp_upload_dir` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that break all references to existing files in the original wp_upload_dir ?

Comment: all files must be transfer to new folder. it simple to rename `wp-content` folder.

Comment: The I suppose I need to rephrase my question: How to make image availible at an arbitrary URL with WordPress without renaming existing wp-content folder.
And I'm learning that the answer is No?

Comment: from wordpress exactly its no! but if you know about PHP you can write your own plugin for that !